# How to convert jbyteArray to Mat?

Tags: android, opencv

I want to convert a byteArray to Mat in native Code.
The byteArray returned from ByteArrayOutpuStream.toByteArray() is originaly an .bmp image. That means the byteArray has also the imageHeader.

On Native side i have jbyteArray where the byteArray is stored.
Now, how to convert this jbyteArray to a Mat for further processing on it?

I think i have to decode it first with cv::imdecode(?,?,?)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the jbyteArray to Mat.

Refer the following link.

https://github.com/ethanrublee/catkin-opencv/blob/master/samples/android/tutorial-3-native/jni/jni_part.cpp

android-opencv project has these samples.